# Recursive find/replace, taking directory depth into consideration

Tags: sed, find, recursive, replace

I've had good luck doing basic find/replace:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i -e "s/<?php include 'http:\/\/www/<?php include '..\//g" \{\} \;
```

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve a similar result, but taking into account the 'depth' of the current directory, and prepending an additional `../` to the replacement string for each level down we are in the structure?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an example of a directory structure and how you would want the files to be changed. It's kind of hard to understand as it is.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sh -c \
'PREFIX=${1//[!/]/}; PREFIX=${PREFIX//\//..\/}; ...' sh {} \;
```

That will set `PREFIX` to `../` when the found file is `dir/filename`. You can then insert your `sed` command into the `...` position, making use of the shell variable `$PREFIX`.

This requires a shell that has the `${var//find/repl}` expansion. That's not specified by POSIX, but `Bash` and some implementations of `ash` have it. If yours doesn't, you'd have to use something else to do the prefix manipulation. In that case, I'd use a single `awk` process to do the prefix manipulation in its `BEGIN` clause, then so the replacement on each line of the file (instead of a separate `sed` process).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this hint!
But it seems that slash has to be escaped even inside square brackets: `PREFIX=${1//[!\/]/}`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task to enforce base urls dependent on directory depth relative to the site root.

Posting the full solution below. It's based on @dubiousjim's answer but uses a slightly different approach with the shell function to avoid quoting problems.

```
fixlinks() {
  # strip the first level depth as we don't need it
  BASE=${1/#\.\//}
  # leave only one slash char for each nested dir
  BASE=${BASE//[!\/]/}
  # replace each / with ../ (escaped to ..\/ to be used as sed replacement part)
  BASE=${BASE//\//..\\\/} 
  if [[ $BASE ]]; then
    # enable debug mode
    set -x
    # add <base> tag leading to site root after <head> for each nested file
    sed -E -i "s/<head>\r?$/<head><base href=\"$BASE\"\/>/g" "$1"
    # silently disable debug mode
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null
  fi
}
# iterate over all files from the site root
find . -name '*.html' | while read file; do fixlinks "$file"; done
```